# Data streaming using streamcontent_from_pid in Yaws/Erlang

Tags: erlang, comet, yaws, data-stream

I desire to **stream data** with `yaws` to my comet application, I have read and worked around to understand it but the example from yaws seems to be a little complicated for me (**I am new to Erlang**). I just cannot get my head around...

here is the example from yaws (I modified a little bit):

```
out(A) ->
    %% Create a random number
    {_A1, A2, A3} = now(),
    random:seed(erlang:phash(node(), 1),
                erlang:phash(A2, A3),
                A3),
    Sz = random:uniform(1),

    Pid = spawn(fun() ->
                        %% Read random junk
                        S="Hello World",
                        P = open_port({spawn, S}, [binary,stream, eof]),
                        rec_loop(A#arg.clisock, P)
                end),

    [{header, {content_length, Sz}},
     {streamcontent_from_pid, "text/html; charset=utf-8", Pid}].


rec_loop(Sock, P) ->
    receive
        {discard, YawsPid} ->
            yaws_api:stream_process_end(Sock, YawsPid);
        {ok, YawsPid} ->
            rec_loop(Sock, YawsPid, P)
    end,
    port_close(P),
    exit(normal).

rec_loop(Sock, YawsPid, P) ->
    receive
        {P, {data, BinData}} ->
            yaws_api:stream_process_deliver(Sock, BinData),
            rec_loop(Sock, YawsPid, P);
        {P, eof} ->
            yaws_api:stream_process_end(Sock, YawsPid)
    end.
```

**What I need is to transform the above script to which can be combined with the following.**

```
mysql:start_link(p1, "127.0.0.1", "root", "azzkikr", "mydb"),
                {data, Results}  = mysql:fetch(p1, "SELECT*FROM messages WHERE id > " ++ LASTID),
                {mysql_result, FieldNames, FieldValues, NoneA, NoneB} = Results,
                parse_data(FieldValues, [], [], [], [], [])
```

Where `parse_data(FieldValues, [], [], [], [], [])` returns a JSON string of the entry..
**Combined** this script should constantly check for a new entry into database and if there is, it should fetch as comet should.

Thank you, May you all go to paradise!

Comment: Would you want to query the database after receiving a request through comet or rather query the database in a loop and respond through comet as soon as there is the required data?

Comment: I'd want query the database in a loop and respond through comet as soon as there is the required data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37641405/409228) explains, sometimes you need to have a process running that's independent of any incoming HTTP requests. For your case, you can use a form of publish/subscribe:

- *Publisher:* when your Erlang node starts up, start some sort of database client process, or a pool of such processes, executing your query and running independently of Yaws.
- *Subscriber:* when Yaws receives an HTTP request and dispatches it to your code, your code subscribes to the publisher. When the publisher sends data to the subscriber, the subscriber streams them back to the HTTP client.

Detailing a full solution here is impractical, but the general steps are:

- When your database client processes start, they register themselves into a [`pg2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/pg2.html) group or something similar. Use something like [`poolboy`](https://github.com/devinus/poolboy) instead of rolling your own process pools, as they're [notoriously tricky](http://basho.com/posts/technical/quickchecking-poolboy-for-fun-and-profit/) to get right. Each database client can be an instance of a [`gen_server`](http://erlang.org/doc/design_principles/gen_server_concepts.html) running a query, receiving database results, and also handling subscription request calls.
- When your Yaws code receives a request, it looks up a database client publisher process and subscribes to it. Subscriptions require calling a function in the database client module, which in turn uses [`gen_server:call/2,3`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_server.html#call-2) to communicate with the actual `gen_server` publisher process. The subscriber uses [Yaws streaming capabilities](http://yaws.hyber.org/stream.yaws) (or [SSE](http://yaws.hyber.org/server_sent_events.yaws) or [WebSocket](http://yaws.hyber.org/websockets.yaws)) to complete the connection with the HTTP client and sends it any required response headers.
- The publisher stores the process ID of the subscriber, and also establishes a [monitor](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#monitor-2) on the subscriber so it can clean up the subscription should the subscriber die or exit unexpectedly.
- The publisher uses the [monitor's reference](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html#id64759) as a unique ID in its messages it sends to that subscriber, so the subscription function returns that reference to the subscriber. The subscriber uses the reference to match incoming messages from the publisher.
- When the publisher gets new query results from the database, it sends the data to each of its subscribers. This can be done with normal Erlang messages.
- The subscriber uses [Yaws streaming functions](http://yaws.hyber.org/stream.yaws) (or [SSE](http://yaws.hyber.org/server_sent_events.yaws) or [WebSocket](http://yaws.hyber.org/websockets.yaws) features) to send query results to the HTTP client.
- When an HTTP client disconnects, the subscriber calls another publisher function to unsubscribe.